# osm2pgsql (v. 1.4.0) "Unknown option -- t" (Usage error)

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I'm trying to import the [OSM sample data](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-PostGIS) from Mastering PostGIS, Chapter 1. I'm on Windows and am using [this](https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/artifacts/osm2pgsql_Release_x64.zip?job=Environment%3A%20arch%3Dx64) x64 binary (v1.4.0) I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118334/download-link-to-osm2pgsql).

The call is as in the book

```
osm2pgsql -H localhost -P 5432 -U postgres -W -d mastering_postgis -S default.style "c:\Users\grego\OneDrive\..\data\greenwich_observatory\greenwich_observatory.osm" -hstore
```

The error I'm getting is

```
2020-12-22 10:23:49  osm2pgsql version 1.4.0 osm2pgsql: unknown option -- t
2020-12-22 10:23:49  ERROR: Usage error. For further information call: osm2pgsql --help
```

Version info is this:

```
osm2pgsql version 1.4.0
```

Compiled using the following library versions:

```
Libosmium 2.15.6
Proj [API 4] Rel. 4.9.3, 15 August 2016
Lua 5.3.4
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a - in `--hstore`. With a single dash, it processed -h and -s which exist but it didn't know what to do with -t.

Comment: Ah fantastic! Thanks a million, Eric. The book unfortunately just shows a single dash there. Hrmpf.